# QGIS messes up attribute table when joining by location

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a layer with attributes that I imported from a .csv and a geopackage that I created.
When I try to do a join by location with both QGIS created an fid column, deletes every value from the first column, leaving the header and then shifts every value to the left. How do you stop if from doing this?
I am using QGIS 3.32.3

As an example:

Before

[image: Before join]

After

[image: After join]

Where every value in the second picture should be one column to the right

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact release of QGIS in use.

Comment: Used a workaround where you import the .csv as a delimited text file and export it as a geopackage with metadata. It ads the fid to the end of the attribute table and can be used normally.